# Unable to dismiss UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

if network not available then it showing alert of "Network not available" but after that loading spinner is not able to dismiss... It continuously showing loading spinner.....

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [self showSpinner];
   [self getDashBoard];
}

- (void) getDashBoard {
       //[API call]
       // if success then
              //assign values from response 
              [self dismissSpinner]
       // else 
       //     [self dismissSpinner]
       //     [Utility displayAlert:@"Error" WithMessage:@"Network not available"];

  }



 #pragma mark - LodingSpinner
 - (void) showSpinner {
     if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
    // use UIAlertView
}
else {
    lodingSpinner = [Utility showProgress];
    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:lodingSpinner animated:NO completion:nil];
     }
}

- (void) dismissSpinner {
      if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
    // use UIAlertView
     }
     else {
         [lodingSpinner dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }
 }
```

Comment: Good for you.  Have you debugged this at all?  There's absolutely no way we can tell from your code what path it's taking, nor why.  Have you verified that it reaches the code you expect?  If it hasn't, have you traced through to see which condition is unexpected?

Comment: I suggest to dismiss Spinner on UIAlertViewController's Ok action

Comment: Yes i have debugged it all.. when code reaches after [self showSpinner] in viewDidAppear it not showing spinner... but when alert of "network not available" disappeared then loading spinner starts... and running continuously...

Comment: I would look into whether or not the variable that tracks your spinner is going out of scope at some point. When you reach the point where you expect it to be dismiss, check to see if the relevant variables are nil.

Comment: To check existence of API you should practice using if ([UIAlertController class]) {...}